# Is there a 4th barrier to computing?

Tags: computability, hypercomputation

I know there are three barriers of computation; the thermodynamic barrier, the light barrier and the quantum barrier. Let’s say we figure out how to send signals FTL, learn how to get rid of excess heat and continue down the ladder of nanotech, picotech and femtotech. Is there a 4th barrier we might encounter at some point and what might that theoretical barrier be?

Comment: This sounds awfully speculative.  At that point we'd be talking about entirely different laws of physics, in which case how could we possibly speculate what the new laws might look like?

Comment: Seems hard to have gates smaller than the size of a single elementary particle.

Comment: Well that’s what femtotech is in theory.